# MySQL: Adding figures during UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to UPDATE a column for a user, so that they can only ADD a value to the existing value. So for example, if the table looked like this:

```
UserID 3  
Total  12
```

User adds `4`, so it's changed to:

```
UserID 3  
Total  16
```

I could obviously do this by doing a query, getting the column value, adding it to the new value, and then updating that column... but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without using a SELECT statement first. Perhaps something using SUM()?

So the query might go:

```
UPDATE Users SET Total=SUM(Total + :total) WHERE UserID = :userID;
```

If so, what's the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `SUM()` since you are just adding the values, `SUM()` adds the values of a column together.

```
UPDATE Users 
SET Total= Total + :total 
WHERE UserID = :userID;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as:

```
UPDATE Users SET Total = Total + :total WHERE UserID = :userID;
```